# Why wordpress orderby post__in is not sorting properly?

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress query is sometime a pain, i'm trying to order posts by post__in like this :

```
$query = array(
        "post_type" => "product",
        "post_status" => "publish",
        "posts_per_page" => 12,
        "paged" => $paged,
        "post__in" => $posts_ids, // <= array of ids (int)
        "orderby" => "post__in"
    );
remove_all_filters('pre_get_posts');
remove_all_filters('posts_orderby');
// Start query
$posts = new Wp_Query($query);
```

But it still output bad order, i have wp version 5.5.3 and from [doc][1] orderby by post__in is available from 3.5, i have already tried ("orderby" => array("post__in")) without success too, i have no third party plugin which may alter this parameter.

Does a tax_query may cause this issue?

Someone can help me please? i missed something ?
[1]: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters

Comment: Does your `$posts_ids` in order that you want?

Comment: Yes they are all good

Answer (score 0):

Add `wp_reset_query()` before the custom query.

```
$query = array(
    "post_type"      => "product",
    "post_status"    => "publish",
    "posts_per_page" => 12,
    "paged"          => $paged,
    "post__in"       => $posts_ids, // <= array of ids (int)
    "orderby"        => "post__in"
);
wp_reset_query();
// Start query
$posts = new Wp_Query($query);
```